# Memory(CPU) usage by Application in Android

Tags: android

i have create my first Application in Android And i want to put it on Android market, before that i want to know that, i want to check how much memory(CPU) used by my Application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Eclipse, on the DDMS page there is a tab called heap which will test you what heap usage you are using.  If you want to see size on the disk then just look in the settings-applications dialog on a phone with the app installed.